# how to Parse Sharepoint 2019 modern UI URL Link in C#

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, web

I am trying to parse below link of sharepoint Modern UI, Link is mentioned below. http://rvsp2019/sites/firstsite/_api/web/GetList(@v1)/RenderExtendedListFormData(itemId=16,formId=%27editform%27,mode=%272%27,options=7)?@v1=%27%2Fsites%2Ffirstsite%2FDL%27

I have to get the itemId from that link for further validation,Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse this url with regular expressions. This code should work with your example url:

```
string s = "http://rvsp2019/sites/firstsite/_api/web/GetList(@v1)/RenderExtendedListFormData(itemId=16,formId=%27editform%27,mode=%272%27,options=7)?@v1=%27%2Fsites%2Ffirstsite%2FDL%27";
Match match = Regex.Match(s, @"itemid=(\d+)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
if (match.Success)
{
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    //key variable here has the itemid value
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

More usefull examples on regular expressions in C# can be found [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex).